# How to convert gwt Date to javascript Date?

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

How to convert gwt Date to javascript Date ?

```
 public native String converToJSDate(Date date)/*-{

    alert(date instanceof Date);  // i get "false" 

  }-*/;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest is to create an equivalent JS date:

```java
JsDate.create((double) date.getTime())
```

Comment: i want to use it inside javascript not java.  from my code, i want to make (date instanceof Date) become true.

Comment: Simply put: you can't. If your code is in JSNI only, then you could try `date instanceof @java.util.Date` but I'm not sure it'd work; you'd better try to do it in Java, using a `isThisADate` method that you'd implement as `date instanceof Date` in Java, and call from JSNI using `@packageOf.MyClass:isThisADate(Ljava/lang/Object;)(date)`

Answer (score 3):

```
public native final JsDate convertToJsDate(Date val) /*-{
    return new $wnd.Date(val.@java.util.Date::getTime()());
...
```

Comment: Doesn't work, compilation failed with "long is not safe in JSNI".